# Trying to grab href URLs from Kayak website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to grab the URLs from each of the cards for flights that appear in [this Kayak website](https://www.kayak.com/flights/AMS-WMI,nearby/2023-02-15/WMI-SOF,nearby/2023-02-18/SOF-BEG,nearby/2023-02-20/BEG-MIL,nearby/2023-02-23/MIL-AMS,nearby/2023-02-25/?sort=bestflight_a&fs=stops=-2&attempt=1&lastms=1675195877028) and I'm getting a `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe` error when I try running the code below. Can someone help me get the right code to grab all of the URLs from the flight results in this page?

```
url = 'https://www.kayak.com/flights/AMS-WMI,nearby/2023-02-15/WMI-SOF,nearby/2023-02-18/SOF-BEG,nearby/2023-02-20/BEG-MIL,nearby/2023-02-23/MIL-AMS,nearby/2023-02-25/?sort=bestflight_a&fs=stops=-2&attempt=1&lastms=1675195877028'
requests = 0

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
agents = ["Firefox/66.0.3","Chrome/73.0.3683.68","Edge/16.16299"]
print("User agent: " + agents[(requests%len(agents))])
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=' + agents[(requests%len(agents))] + '"')    
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/junerodriguez/Downloads/chromedriver_mac_arm64/chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
sleep(randint(8,10))

xp_hrefs = "//div[@class='above-button']//a[contains(@class,'booking-link')]/href[@class='col col-best']"

hrefs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xp_hrefs)
hrefs
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Selenium you should use XPaths locating web elements, not their attributes.
To extract the `href` attribute values you need to collect all these `a` web elements into a list, and then iterate over that list to extract the `href` attribute from each web element in the list, as following:

```py
hrefs = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='above-button']//a[contains(@class,'booking-link')]")]
```

In the code above you are gettin all matching web elements to a list  and then for each `link` element in that list applying `link.get_attribute('href')` to eaxtract the `href` attribute value.
The result is collected into `hrefs` list.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the links from all the *href* attributes within the [website](https://www.kayak.com/flights/AMS-WMI,nearby/2023-02-15/WMI-SOF,nearby/2023-02-18/SOF-BEG,nearby/2023-02-20/BEG-MIL,nearby/2023-02-23/MIL-AMS,nearby/2023-02-25/?sort=bestflight_a&fs=stops=-2&attempt=1&lastms=1675195877028) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.kayak.com/flights/AMS-WMI,nearby/2023-02-15/WMI-SOF,nearby/2023-02-18/SOF-BEG,nearby/2023-02-20/BEG-MIL,nearby/2023-02-23/MIL-AMS,nearby/2023-02-25/?sort=bestflight_a&fs=stops=-2&attempt=1&lastms=1675195877028")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[role='link'][href]")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`get_attribute("innerHTML")`*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.kayak.com/flights/AMS-WMI,nearby/2023-02-15/WMI-SOF,nearby/2023-02-18/SOF-BEG,nearby/2023-02-20/BEG-MIL,nearby/2023-02-23/MIL-AMS,nearby/2023-02-25/?sort=bestflight_a&fs=stops=-2&attempt=1&lastms=1675195877028")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@role='link' and @href]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.18wgSzIaLAlgpzrTH2pViLaYAeeTFjgE.81197.36c89f7717e84ac7a4ee2898627fa251&h=40d03211086c&sub=E-191e8b4083a&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M0', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.47F3EeHCWiIEdn9PX-8xhQ.41000.a6f675f0a632a9d55b0fab7f1b09f9d8&h=8dce29003385&sub=E-10f42a14593&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M1', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.18wgSzIaLAlgpzrTH2pViLaYAeeTFjgE.81397.58fb639ccf8938f61eec808f1e13c556&h=ba02be2bf0dc&sub=E-191e8b4083a&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M2', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.18wgSzIaLAlgpzrTH2pViLaYAeeTFjgE.81197.aca9104db06bae99e4f55a158dfd3ff2&h=61a4dc653dc3&sub=E-191e8b4083a&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M4', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.18wgSzIaLAlgpzrTH2pViLaYAeeTFjgE.81397.bcc92e8ae656b0e298dbe8a6555bd825&h=ece97a1b9509&sub=E-191e8b4083a&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M5', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.18wgSzIaLAlgpzrTH2pViLaYAeeTFjgE.80697.732461bd95055d2478850abf1741221f&h=c94d3b283c0a&sub=E-191e8b4083a&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M6', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.18wgSzIaLAlgpzrTH2pViLaYAeeTFjgE.80997.215cabd8ee10582a0d6b94c20dfb95ad&h=b493996d9e9d&sub=E-191e8b4083a&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M7', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.18wgSzIaLAlgpzrTH2pViLaYAeeTFjgE.80697.cabd6f6051c17b3cd7f9129454607d0e&h=917f7fb0f2f5&sub=E-191e8b4083a&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M8', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.18wgSzIaLAlgpzrTH2pViLaYAeeTFjgE.80997.07496f1f93e916d757ec284da1ef4638&h=52abbdb7d13a&sub=E-191e8b4083a&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M11', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.eNCwACMVOeJpd4CyPwn0EI6M4XD8KcmF.71697.a1633218d7cbd5eb2fe950504a6207a9&h=c8fe9769a628&sub=E-15b10c5af5f&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M12', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.eNCwACMVOeJpd4CyPwn0EI6M4XD8KcmF.71997.ebd834f5c265ae428e1bdbb3637a606b&h=d80290f43a93&sub=E-15b10c5af5f&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M13', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.eNCwACMVOeJpd4CyPwn0EI6M4XD8KcmF.71697.c7a2ace471ba5c35334014e91956f849&h=2f3b292c166e&sub=E-15b10c5af5f&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M14', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.eNCwACMVOeJpd4CyPwn0EI6M4XD8KcmF.71997.a281f919b379469a223fb34ed5510409&h=913a810b8e80&sub=E-15b10c5af5f&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M15', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.eNCwACMVOeJpd4CyPwn0EI6M4XD8KcmF.71697.4fdb4fded43ccbf47dcdcad01bf919e6&h=ea07410d1dda&sub=E-15b10c5af5f&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M16', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.eNCwACMVOeJpd4CyPwn0EI6M4XD8KcmF.71997.23101dac562249519c55956ba4cc7abf&h=45c62f765f1f&sub=E-15b10c5af5f&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M17', 'https://www.kayak.com/book/flight?code=OiFir3l_8L.eNCwACMVOeJpd4CyPwn0EI6M4XD8KcmF.71697.1377d5650be1523cc39b1849b7d9bbdf&h=c04d73c3ac61&sub=E-15b10c5af5f&pageOrigin=F..RP.FE.M18']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```